# document.documentElement.clientWidth vs window.innerWidth performance

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, async-await, viewport

I have a performance problem with `window.innerWidth` on mobile and with `document.documentElement.clientWidth` on desktop.

Is not a problem of dimension but a problem of **timing**. The return of `window.innerWidth` on mobile seems to be slower and the same for `document.documentElement.clientWidth` on desktop.

Is it possible?

thx

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Everything's possible :)

Comment: For JavaScript performance testing, there was a page called jsperf.org, but it's down now. You can try something like https://www.measurethat.net/ or http://jsbench.github.io/ instead.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Instead of asking us a very vague “is that possible” question, you should describe what your actual problem is, and give code to reproduce it. (And I am guessing you mean more of a _timing_ than an actual “performance” problem to begin with.)

Comment: There is also `getBoundingClientRect`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: I benchmarked with https://jsbench.me/. On desktop Firefox `window.innerWidth` is 50 times faster than `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and on desktop Chrome it's even 500 times faster. On mobile Chrome it's even 2000 times faster. It looks like there are big differences between browsers.

Comment: Why are you accessing the window width so often that it becomes a performance issue?

Comment: @Bergi I don't access the window width so often, just one time but in a flow without asynchron management.
I solved by changing the flow but I was curious to understand why.